# Last Item of ListView cannot be displayed

Tags: android, listview

I want to display a list of items and an `EditText` at top of `ListView`, my list has 5 items, when run the program just shows 4 items. The code is below:

```
if(position == 0) {
                view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.item_search, null);
                final EditText et_search = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_search);
                return view;
            }

Item item = items.get(position-1);
Log.i(TAG, "position="+position+", items.size()="+items.size()+", list.getCount()="+list.getCount());
.....
```

In this case only shows 4 items, 
and also i Loged the output:

```
: position=1, items.size()=5, list.getCount()=6
: position=2, items.size()=5, list.getCount()=6
: position=3, items.size()=5, list.getCount()=6
: position=4, items.size()=5, list.getCount()=6
```

from the output we can see that it loops 4 times and also `position-1` (from 0 to 3) it dosen't go to the next item,
if anyone knows what is the problem please reply the post.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see a for-loop in the code above...

Comment: Add full code of getView()

Comment: it is BaseAdapter and loop automatically, no need to for loop

Comment: have you used EditText for search ?

Comment: No, there is only one EditText at the top of ListView, just used for search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below modification of `getView()` into your Adapter will work

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size() + 1;
}
```

---

***But this is not a good way. Better way is to add `EditText` into your Layout code above the `ListView`. In this case you no need to add check for position.***

Answer (score 0):

if position == 0,it will return...;

```
if(position == 0) {
  view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.item_search, null);
  final EditText et_search = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_search);
  return view;
}
```

so you can only see the count of log is items.size()-1;

and you'd better show your adapter,I think list.getCount() does't right too;